# How to perform deployment swap on an Azure WebSite using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service

This question refers to the application slots feature for Azure Server Manager (ASM) WebSites that enables the ability to create a staging website under an existing one. I'd like to swap my site's staging and production environments using Powershell, but I haven't found the way to do it with the currently available commands. Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot -Name "your web site name" -Force

Comment: Thank you! I just realized that the new version (0.7.3) of Azure SDK Tools has been released quite recently. It's not yet indicated by WebPI, [but it's available on GitHub](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools/releases).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this PowerShell cmdlet:
Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot [[-Name]  ] [[-Slot1]  ] [[-Slot2]  ] [-Force] [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [ ]

`[-Force]` parameter is used in order to not confirm the swap operation and directly execute

An Example:

```
C:\PS>Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot -Name YourWebsite
```